# Differences between winsock and BSD socket implementations

Tags: sockets

What are the major differences between Winsock and *nix BSD socket implementations?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below if they've helped you out. Personally, I have found both answers present as of writing to be quite helpful.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look [here](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html).
To that, I'd drop one more difference, winsocks supports overlapped I/O (with callbacks etc.) through functions like WSARecv (and other similar), which can make porting to bsd-sockets harder.
Also, most functions in winsocks has their Wsa* counterpart, which sometimes offers more options (or at least requires more parameters ;) ), like [recv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121(VS.85).aspx) and [WSARecv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741688(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 7):

See this section of the documentation:

[Porting Socket Applications to Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740096(VS.85).aspx)