# Using sys/socket.h functions on windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I'm attempting to utilize the socket.h functions within Windows. Essentially, I'm currently looking at the sample code at https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html#datagram. I understand that socket.h is a Unix function -- is there anyway I can easily emulate that environment while compiling this sample code? Does a different IDE / compiler change anything?

Otherwise, I imagine that I need to utilize a virtualized Linux environment, which may be best anyways as the code will most likely be running in a UNIX environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use [**Cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.com/) (Unix emulation library).
2. Port to [**Winsock**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673(v=VS.85).aspx) (Windows standard library).

Cygwin: lets you compile your Unix sources mostly untouched, but ties you to the Cygwin emulation library. This have two implications: general performance -no only network- will probably be less than optimal; and the target environment must have (at run time) the Cygwin DLL installed.

Winsock: this requires you to replace `sys/socket.h`  (BSD sockets library, UNIX standard for the TCP/IP stack) with `winsock2.h`, and rewrite some parts of the code - not much, but some.

Some related questions with valuable info:

[Differences between winsock and BSD socket implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383286/differences-between-winsock-and-bsd-socket-implementations)

[Some Issues About Cygwin[Linux in Windows] (socket,thread,other programming and shell issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087435/cygwin-socket-thread-other-programming-issues-some-question-about-cygwin)

[Examples for Winsock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399377/examples-for-winsock)

Comment: +1 for winsock and examples. I have been using winsock. I only need to change a small fraction of codes in order to port my Unix program to Windows. It is easy.

Comment: There are more surprises the other way around though :)
For example, `select` on windows ignores the first argument, so naturally, winsock programmers put zero there for `maxfd`. Royal pain :)

Comment: 2021 update - another option is MSYS2 which is a fork of cygwin and has similar considerations -- a binary would have to be distributed with MSYS2 runtime DLL.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Winsock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock) library.

Answer (score 2):

Writing cross platform network applications is not easy with what the BSD standard provides you. Sure it will work but you'll have to make some replacements like replacing ioctl (if needed) with ioctlsocket (on windows). More differences [here](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html).

My advice is to use a library that hides these ugly differences and provides a unified way of communicating. I personally use [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). You have plenty of examples that show you how to create a server and a client. Copy from the samples and see how they do it there. Their mailing lists are of great help also (don't forget to use the PRF - see the source tree for the Problem-Report-Form). You can borrow the books for more information. Important note: by using ace you can use ACE wrapper functions like socket, setsockopt, ioctl etc. without worry that they will not work. Unfortunately this adds a library dependency which is not always an option. But ACE has more powerfull features which I'm sure you'll like once you discover them. Hints: Reactor, Proactor.