# how to make a socket server listen on local file

Tags: python, sockets

Just like MySQL server's `/tmp/mysql.sock` and client write to this file throught socket or any suggestion to share content between independent process (one update, one read) without `memcached` or NoSQL server, without multithread or multiprocess.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
# Echo server program
import socket,os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    os.remove("/tmp/socketname")
except OSError:
    pass
s.bind("/tmp/socketname")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()


# Echo client program
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("/tmp/socketname")
s.send(b'Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Received ' + repr(data))
```

Shamelessly copy-pasted from [the Python mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-October/1133164.html).

Comment: this does not work under windows

Comment: @Har yes - it relies on Unix socket files which Windows does not support (boo, Windows)

Comment: I get protocol wrong type for socket:
>  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> s.connect('/dev/log')
error: [Errno 91] Protocol wrong type for socket

Comment: Works fine under Cygwin. And when it works under Cygwin, it works even better under Linux/Unix. Are you perhaps trying it out under Windows without Cygwin? If so, try out the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952733/using-sys-socket-h-functions-on-windows

Comment: Here's an archive.org link to [the Python mailing list](https://web.archive.org/web/20120208194121/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-October/1133164.html) as it's no longer available.