# How can one maintain communication with a child process if the parent process restarts?

Tags: python, linux

Im writing a simple job scheduler and I need to maintain some basic level of communication from the scheduler ( parent ) to spawned processes ( children ).
Basically I want to be able to send signals from scheduler -> child and also inform the the scheduler of a child's exit status.

Generally this is all fine and dandy using regular subprocess Popen with signaling / waitpid.  My issues is that I want to be able to restart the scheduler without impacting running jobs, and re-establish comm once the scheduler restarts.

Ive gone through a few ideas, nothing feels "right".
Right now I have a simple wrapper script that maintains communication with the scheduler using named pipes, and the wrapper will actually run the scheduled command.  This seems to work well in most cases but I have seen it subject to some races, mainly due to how namedpipes need the connection to be alive in order to read/write ( no buffering ).

Im considering trying linux message queues instead, but not sure if that's the right path.  Another option is setup a server socket accept on the scheduler and have sub-processes connect to the scheduler when they start, and re-establish the connection if it breaks.  This might be overkill, but maybe the most robust.
Its a shame I have to go through all this trouble since I cant just "re-attached" the child process on restart ( I realize there are reasons for this ).

Any other thoughts?  This seems like a common problem any scheduler would hit, am I missing some obvious solution here?

Comment: I think there's no way except using a message queue like zeromq, kafka, redis or a socket server/unix domain socket. You might want to look into [Supervisor](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor) which by itself is a job scheduler, to know how they handled it, AFIAK they don't allow child daemon process.

Comment: I think using unix domain sockets like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361625/how-to-make-a-socket-server-listen-on-local-file) is a good idea. Each child process will receive commands from a local socket file, and the parent will write to it.