# How can I compile ndpiReader.c that comes with nDPI library in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, cross-compiling

I want to create a .exe of `ndpiReader.c` demo program that comes with `nDPI library`. I was successful to compile it on Ubuntu using commands specified on their github page as bellow:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

I have tried to cross compile it using GCC inside Ubuntu but I wasn't successful. I also tried to use the `pcapExample.sln` to compile it in Visual Studio 2012, but I keep getting error messages like:

> Error 29  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ndpi_api.h': No such file or directory

Although `ndpi_api.h` and all other files that I get this error for already are listed in the project solution explorer.
Has anyone actually been able to make a win32 executable out of this `ndpiReader.c` file? If yes, please specify the steps, requirements, or a link.

`nDPI` lib is hosted here: https://github.com/ntop/nDPI

`ndpiReader.c` is hosted here: https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/tree/dev/example

`pcapExample.sln` is hosted here: https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/tree/dev/example/Win32

Comment: The code does not seem portable at all although there is a Win32 directory and a solution. For example, it includes `<sys/socket.h>` and this is not so easily portable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952733/using-sys-socket-h-functions-on-windows another issue is the `../config.h` file. Where does that point to?

Comment: Given that there are no instructions for a Windows build, have you considered raising that as a bug on the GitHub project, or with ntop, who seem to maintain this library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw from your other questions that you had already tried to compile this with [CYGWIN](http://cygwin.com/) and ran into a number of problems.

Here’s a step-by-step guide I just used to compile nDPI (including the ndpiReader.exe example):

**Install CYGWIN:**

1. Accept the default directories, and pick a mirror.
2. At the **Select Packages** step, expand the **Devel** category, and select the following developer packages to install:

   - autoconf
   - autoconf2.5
   - automake
   - automake1.15
   - binutils
   - cmake
   - cygwin-devel
   - gcc-core
   - gcc-tools-epoch2-autoconf
   - gcc-tools-epoch2-automake
   - libtool
   - make
   - pkg-config
   - w32api-headers
   - w32api-runtime

**Install libpcap under CYGWIN:**

1. Download and unpack the [Winpcap Developer's pack](http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm).
2. Copy libpacket.a and libwpcap.a from WpdPack\Lib\ to cygwin\lib\
3. In cygwin\lib, copy libwpcap.a to libpcap.a
4. In cygwin\usr\include, create a pcap directory
5. Copy all headers from WpdPack\Include to cygwin\usr\include\pcap

I'm sure you've installed winpcap already as part of everything else you've tried, but double-check that the necessary (packet.dll and wpcap.dll) libraries are already in cygwin\c\WINDOWS\system32.

Now you've got all the necessary tools and libraries to compile nDPI on Windows!

**Building nDPI**

1. Download and unpack nDPI again in a clean directory, so you don't get tripped up by any issues from the previous build you tried.
2. Open a CYGWIN terminal, and cd into the nDPI directory.
3. Run autogen.sh

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   ```

   This should complete without any errors.

   *If it stops with "**somepackage** is missing: please install it and try again," you've missed installing a CYGWIN package that is needed to build the source.*

   *If it stops with "Missing libpcap(-dev) library," double-check the previous steps you did to copy libpcap.a in cygwin\lib.*
4. autogen.sh should start running the configure stage for you.  (If it doesn't, or part of this stage fails, you can rerun configure after fixing any issue.)

   ```
   ./configure
   ```

   After checking for a number of things, configure will end by creating a Makefile.
5. Build the nDPI library, by running make.

   ```
   make
   ```

   It will build the library, then try to build the examples, but fail because it can't find *pcap.h*
6. cd into the example directory, and manually compile ndpiReader.c by adding **-I/usr/include/pcap** to the command:

   ```
   cd example/
   gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../src/include -I/usr/include/pcap -g -O2 -c -o ndpiReader.o ndpiReader.c
   ```

   *I included my command as an example.  If your compiler command is slightly different, just add -I/usr/include/pcap to what your Makefile had invoked.*
7. Leave the example directory, and resume the make.

   ```
   cd ..
   make
   ```

   This last step will link ndpiReader with the ndpi library, and create the executable you're looking for.