# How can I compile nDPI library on Windows?

Tags: compilation

The library comes with instructions on how to compile it on Linux:

- ./autogen.sh
- ./configure
- make

But I can't find any source on the Internet to help me compile this code directly on Windows, just as if I never had a Linux machine.

`nDPI` is hosted here: https://github.com/ntop/nDPI

Comment: the documentation says: "In addition to Unix, we also support Windows, in order to provide you a cross-platform DPI experience"
but there is no mention of how to compile it on Windows

Comment: See my comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938032/how-can-i-compile-ndpireader-c-that-comes-with-ndpi-library-in-windows.  Also note that the sample project appears to build no separate library and so I suspect that this may be unsupported.

Comment: I've [answered this question elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31083740/4151918), but have been asked not to repeat the same answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a linux-like CLI using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) (very useful tool) and cross compile to Windows. It's not a complicated process and there is a lot of documentation around the Internet. I recommend using the [MinGW 32 cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182408/manual-for-cross-compiling-a-c-application-from-linux-to-windows).

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit some lines of source code and add the files
ntop_win32.h and ntop_win32.c
Then you can compile nDPI with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NFStream](https://github.com/nfstream/nfstream) which provide Windows support and use nDPI as a DPI engine.