# Problems with cygwin build dll for use in windows app

Tags: dll, cygwin

I use Cygwin to build source code to DLL used by windows app.

When I use `GCC core` / `GCC g++`, the app crash if it calls function (which includes `printf` or `malloc`) in DLL.

When I use `Mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` / `Mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` it reports error like `sys/socket.h：No such file or directory`.

Can anyone explain how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is due to the tentative to build a stand alone DLL (not depending on cygwin1.dll) using cygwin only specific tools. 
You have collision between multiple malloc and other C library call present in cygwin1.dll.

The second is due to the fact that `sys/socket.h` does not exist on Windows
see for possible solution:
[Using sys/socket.h functions on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952733/using-sys-socket-h-functions-on-windows)

So you need to define what is your target : Cygwin/Posix or Windows and choose programming style and tools accordingly, you can not mix.

Comment: Hi, for the first problem, I build a DLL (depends on cygwin1.dll), and create a windows console app with Visual Studio to load the DLL, and call a function in it. If the function contains malloc, the app crashes. So Why there are multiple malloc? Thanks.

Comment: Visual  Studio program uses the Windows C malloc, the Cygwin DLL uses the one in cygwin1.dll. You need to use the same tools for both app and dll