# Compile go program with C dependency for Windows

Tags: go, makefile, apache-kafka, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Building go works fine for pure go project with pure go dependencies. But when building a project with a C dependency, it fails on Windows:

```
go build -a -o bin/xyz.exe ./xyz/main.go
go: downloading gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1 v1.4.2
go: downloading github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go v1.4.2
# gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka
In file included from C:\Users\VssAdministrator\go\pkg\mod\gopkg.in\confluentinc\confluent-kafka-go.v1@v1.4.2\kafka\00version.go:24:
./librdkafka/rdkafka.h:83:10: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/socket.h> /* for sockaddr, .. */
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:10: build-windows] Error 2
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '2'.
Finishing: CmdLine
```

As can be seen from the output above, I'm using a Makefile, and my azure-pipelines.yml looks like this:

```yml
...
- script: 'make package-windows'
...
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
build-windows:
    go build -a -o bin/xyz.exe ./xyz/main.go
```

I also tried setting GOOS and GOARCH, to no avail:

```
build-windows:
    GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -o bin/xyz.exe ./xyz/main.go
```

So how can I build this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have much to do with Go - it seems you're doing everything correctly in that regard. The issue is that the library you're using needs `sys/socket.h` which simply doesn't exist on Windows (see [Using sys/socket.h functions on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952733/using-sys-socket-h-functions-on-windows)).

Your options are similar to what's mentioned in the other answer:

1. Try to build using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).
2. Modify the library to use Winsock instead of `sys/socket.h`.
3. Find a different library, one that supports Windows (the author of the library you're using [specifically said Windows is not supported](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/537#issuecomment-699633261)).

Comment: Thanks. librdkafka does [support Windows](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/tree/master/win32) via msbuild, but confluent-kafka does in fact not seem to officially, although a couple of people have managed to [build it on Windows](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/128) with and without Cygwin - I will check that out.